# Access Outlets from a different class

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, iboutlet

So heres my issue. I assume its a simple one but i just cannot figure out why this is not working.

I need to access Outlets (UITextField, UITableView, UIActivityIndicatorView, etc.) in one class (RootViewController) from a different class (ServiceController).

I have this currently (only showing whats need) :

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController{
    UITextField *textField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

- (void)startService;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize textField;

- (void)startService{
    ServiceController *service = [[ServiceController alloc] init];
    [service start];
    [service release];
}

@end
```

ServiceController.h

```
@class RootViewController;

@interface ServiceController : NSObject{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;

- (void)start;

@end
```

ServiceController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation ServiceController

@synthesize rootViewController;

- (void)start{
    [((RootViewController*)rootViewController).textField setText:@"HELLO !"];
    NSLog(@"CALLED !");
}

@end
```

I do not see why this is not working, i use the same method to do the same thing from the RootViewController to the DetailViewController and it works fine. I checked to see if there were any other declaration in the detail/root controllers to allow that to work but i did not notice any.

PS: everything is being called successfully and "CALLED !" is being logged, just whatever i do to the outlet(s) has no effect.

Comment: Is your ServiceController connected to the RootViewController properly in an XIB file?

Comment: the Service Controller does not have an XIB file. If it helps, code completion recognizes all the methods and outlets from rootViewController while im typing and there are no warnings.

Does the rootViewController need an IBOutlet to the ServiceController ?

Comment: No - your ServiceController needs to have its rootViewController property set. You can either do this in an XIB file or explicitly in code: myServiceController.rootViewController = myRootViewController;

Comment: Thank You Luke it now works perfectly. That was really a stupid overlook on my part. Of course its not going to set anything on the view if i dont tell it what the view is *face palm*. Please post that as an answer so that I can Accept it. Thanks Again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ServiceController` needs to have its `rootViewController` property set. You can either do this in an XIB file or explicitly in code:

`myServiceController.rootViewController = myRootViewController;`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't set the `rootViewController`.
Try adding :

```
ServiceController *service = [[ServiceController alloc] init];

// set the property here
[service setRootViewController:self];

[service start];
[service release];
```

Comment: To add more detail to this, sending any message to nil in Objective-C is a no-op.  So in your case calling `textField` on a `nil` object returns `nil`, and the subsequent `setText` call does nothing as well.

Comment: that is exactly what i forgot to do.